# HAProxy log-format directive ignored

Tags: logging, haproxy

I've recently upgraded to haproxy 1.6.3, and I've provided a default `log-format` directive for all HTTP/TCP requests as follows:

```
defaults
    log-format %hr\ %ST\ %B\ %Ts
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    option http-server-close
    maxconn 2000
    timeout client 3600s
    timeout server 3600s
    timeout connect 5s
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
```

However, when I restart the server and log entries begin to be written, they are written using haproxy's default HTTP/TCP log formats:

> Feb  8 14:55:41 localhost haproxy[6770]: host - - [08/Feb/2016:21:55:41 +0000] "POST /path/to/service/1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 841 "" "" 43359 499 "frontend" "backend" "server" 0 0 0 22 22 ---- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "" ""
>
> Feb  8 14:54:05 localhost haproxy[6771]: host:port [08/Feb/2016:14:54:05.469] frontend backend 1/0/4 147 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0

Why is my `log-format` being ignored? I receive no warnings or alerts on restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I had configured a `log-format` directive in the defaults section, there were some frontends that had set `option tcplog` and `option httplog clf` which were overriding the log format I had configured.

The [haproxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#log-format) is a bit misleading here:

> This directive specifies the log format string that will be used for all logs
>   resulting from traffic passing through the frontend using this line. If the
>   directive is used in a defaults section, all subsequent frontends will use
>   the same log format.